# C++ passing in string to map

Tags: c++, string, unordered-map

In the following `for` loop, I test if a letter in a query is in an `unordered_map<string, int>`. If it is not, I print out some things.

```cpp
queries = [ ["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["a", "e"], ["a", "a"], ["x", "x"] ]
```

```cpp
for (vector<string>& q : queries) {
    int start = index[q[0]], end = index[q[1]];
    if (index.find("z") == index.end()) {cout << "z" << '\n';
}
```

`index` only contains `a, b, c`. Correspondingly, the output is this:

```
z
z
z
z
z
```

Which it should be, because one of the queries has an `z` in it. Printing the size of `index` gives 3.

However, if I run this:

```cpp
for (vector<string>& q : queries) {
    int start = index[q[0]], end = index[q[1]];
    if (index.find(q[0]) == index.end()) {cout << "z" << '\n';
}
```

I don't get any output, but I expect output for `x` because that isn't in `index`.

Why is this?

Comment: The answer is coming soon (from someone) but please: Make a [mcve] to make it easier for people to help you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

By the description of the operator `[]` of map in [cppreferance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

`index[q[0]]` created the entry of the key `"x"`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) for a `std::(unordered_)map` creates a new entry in the map if the requested key is not found.

> `index` only contains `a, b, c`.

In your first example, `index.find("z")` will return `index.end()` if `q[0]` and `q[1]` are never `"z"`, which is true in your example.

However, by the time your loop finishes, `index` will not contain just `a, b, c` like you think.  It will actually contain `a, b, c, e, x`.  When you initialize `start` and `end` with the values of `index[q[0]]` and `index[q[1]]`, the `operator[]` will insert the values of `q[0]` and `q[1]` into `index` if they do not already exist.

> I don't get any output, but I expect output for `x` because that isn't in `index`.

In your second example, `index.find(q[0])` will **never** return `index.end()`, because of initializing `start` and `end` with the values of `index[q[0]]` and `index[q[1]]`.  Every value in `q[0]` and `q[1]` gets added into `index`.  So, adding the value of `q[0]` and then searching for the value of `q[0]` will always succeed, and never return `index.end()`.

So yes, there actually *IS* an entry for `"x"` in `index`, when the loop reaches the last `vector` in `queries` containing `"x"` strings and the `operator[]` adds them into `index`.